# How to write query in morphia for filters

Tags: morphia

How convert following mongo query into morphia query.

```
db.sales.aggregate([
  {
  $project: {
     items: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$items",
           as: "item",
           cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
        }
     }
  }
}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that neither Morphia nor the [official Java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/) support $filter via a helper function yet. But you could do this:

```
    AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$project", new Document("_id", 0)
                    .append("items", new Document("$filter",
                            new Document("input", "$items")
                                    .append("as", "item")
                                    .append("cond", new Document("$gte", Arrays.asList("$$item.price", 100)))
                    ))),
            new Document("$unwind", "$items")
    ));


    // Print for demo
    for (Document dbObject : output) {
        System.out.println(dbObject);
    }
```

Since Morphia required the Java driver all of these classes should already via available inside the `com.mongodb` package.